# How do I "trim" this JSON with PHP?

Tags: php, json

I have a JSON that's strangely formatted ...but it's the way I receive it. Because the arrays inside are huge, simply copying and pasting it takes a long time, so I'm wondering if there's a PHP way to do it.

The way I get it is like this:

```
{"count":459,"results":[{"title":"Something ....}],"params":{"limit..},"type":"Listing","pagination":{"..":5}}
```

But I want to get only the "results" array, basically the part of `[{"title":"Something ....}]`. How would I do that?

Comment: crazy plan: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: you don't mangle json strings. you decode the json to a native structure, mangle THAT using native tools, then re-encode to json. mangling the json directly will probably just corrupt it, and you end up with nothing at all.

Comment: `$json = json_decode("Your-String-Here")` and then (according to yr code) you have an object with `$json->results` as array

Comment: I'll try that, thanks a lot :)

Comment: I'm a big fan of crazy @Dagon

Comment: Your json does not return an array. See my answer with tested code.

Answer (score 1):

Do

```
$arr = json_decode(your_json, true);
```

If you ned it as JSON again, do

```
json_encode($arr['results']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get to that part as follows:

```
$json = '{"count":459,"results":[{"title":"Something ...."}],"params":{"limit":".."},"type":"Listing","pagination":{"..":5}}';
$obj = json_decode($json);
echo $obj->results[0]->title;
```

Outputs:

> Something ....

Answer (score 0):

You have to decode your json. Be sure that the json is valid!

**Your decoded json returns an object** of type `stdClass` instead of an array!

See below the *tested* code:

```
$json = '{"count":459,"results":[{"title":"Something ...."}],"params":{"limit": "foo"},"type":"Listing","pagination":{"foo":5}}';

$decoded = json_decode($json);
```

So you can access array `results` from the **object** `$decoded`:

```
print_r($decoded->results);
```

*But, in the array, there are objects, thus:*

```
echo $decoded->results[0]->title; // Something ....
```